# SQL error in procedure with error-code = 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and i got error while inserting this procedure , below is the error shown, please if anyone can help.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE esperance_gain
BEGIN
declare i int(10);
declare E int(20);
set E:=0;
Select count(*) into nb_lignes from questionnaire;
set i:=1;
while (i<=nb_lignes) LOOP
select question4,question7,question8 from questionnaire where i=identifiant;
case question7
when question7='moins de 1dt' then 
case question8
when question8='certain' then set E:=E+0.5;
when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.75);
when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.5);
when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.25);
when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(0.5*0);
end case;
when question7='entre 1dt et 5dt' then
case question8
when question8='certain' then set E:=E+3;
when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(3*0.75);
when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(3*0.5);
when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(3*0.25);
when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(3*0);
end case;
when question7='entre 5dt et 15dt' then
case question8
when question8='certain' then set E:=E+10;
when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(10*0.75);
when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(10*0.5);
when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(10*0.25);
when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(10*0);
end case;
when question7='entre 15dt et 20dt' then
case question8
when question8='certain' then set E:=E+17.5;
when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.75);
when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.5);
when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.25);
when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(17.5*0);
end case;
when question7='plus de 20dt' then
case question8
when question8='certain' then 
case question4
when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*1);
when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*1);
when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*1);
end case;
when question8='fort probable' then 
case question4
when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.75);
when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.75);
when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.75);
end case;
when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then 
case question4
when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.5);
when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.5);
when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.5);
end case;
when question8='peu probable' then 
case question4
when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.25);
when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.25);
when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.25);
end case;
when question8='probabilité nulle' then
case question4
when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0);
when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0);
when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0);
end case;
end case;
set i:=i+1;
END LOOP;
END
```

This the error shown:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
declare i int(10);
declare E int(20);
set E:=0;
Select count(*) into n' at line 2
```

I tried it in oracle10g it works finely but MySQL is making me mad

Comment: Have you defined a different delimiter than `;`?

Comment: Yes i defined a limiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some missing key words and also like vhu already said you missed the parenthesis.

I recommend to set the delimiter so there is no problem with the procedure body and the used `;`. You declared no variable with the name `nb_lignes`, i added that to the procedure. Also you missed one `end case` and the second loop was 
not necessary i removed it and replaced the `END LOOP` with `END WHILE`.

I hope it helps.

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE esperance_gain()
BEGIN
    declare i int(10);
    declare E int(20);
    declare nb_lignes int;
    set E:=0;
    Select count(*) into nb_lignes from questionnaire;
    set i:=1;
    while (i<=nb_lignes) do 
        select question4,question7,question8 from questionnaire where i=identifiant;
        case question7
            when question7='moins de 1dt' then 
            case question8
                when question8='certain' then set E:=E+0.5;
                when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.75);
                when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.5);
                when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(0.5*0.25);
                when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(0.5*0);
            end case;
            when question7='entre 1dt et 5dt' then
            case question8
                when question8='certain' then set E:=E+3;
                when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(3*0.75);
                when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(3*0.5);
                when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(3*0.25);
                when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(3*0);
            end case;
            when question7='entre 5dt et 15dt' then
            case question8
                when question8='certain' then set E:=E+10;
                when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(10*0.75);
                when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(10*0.5);
                when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(10*0.25);
                when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(10*0);
            end case;
            when question7='entre 15dt et 20dt' then
            case question8
                when question8='certain' then set E:=E+17.5;
                when question8='fort probable' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.75);
                when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.5);
                when question8='peu probable' then set E:=E+(17.5*0.25);
                when question8='probabilité nulle' then set E:=E+(17.5*0);
            end case;
            when question7='plus de 20dt' then
            case question8
                when question8='certain' then 
                case question4
                    when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*1);
                    when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*1);
                    when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*1);
                end case;
                when question8='fort probable' then 
                case question4
                    when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.75);
                    when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.75);
                    when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.75);
                end case;
                when question8='en fonction des prochains jeux' then 
                case question4
                    when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.5);
                    when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.5);
                    when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.5);
                end case;
                when question8='peu probable' then 
                case question4
                    when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0.25);
                    when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0.25);
                    when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0.25);
                end case;
                when question8='probabilité nulle' then
                case question4
                    when question4='Oui' then set E:=E+(60*0);
                    when question4='Parfois' then set E:=E+(35*0);
                    when question4='Non' then set E:=E+(20*0);
                end case;
            end case;
        end case;
    set i:=i+1;
    END WHILE;
END \\

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sorry mr,i would like display a message after the loop of while like this:select concat('l espérance de gain réalisée par toute la population est égale à',E);...but any message is displayed after or in this loop..can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parenthesis after the procedure name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE esperance_gain()
```

Relevant section in MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)